# R: Unable to install R packages from source after upgrading to R 4.0 on macOS 10.15

Tags: r, macos, installation

I just upgraded to R 4.0 and am trying to re-install some packages.
However, it seems that I'm now unable to install from source.

For example, when running `install.packages("rlang")` and answering `yes` when asked `Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)`, I get the following error message:

```
In file included from capture.c:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rinternals.h:39:11: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file
      not found
# include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [capture.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
```

Anyone any idea how to fix this? I know I can just install the binary version, but it seems that this could remain an annoying problem for future package installations as well, if not fixed.

Thanks a lot!

---

If it helps, here is the output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps (I don't have a macos), but I've heard many such problems are remedied when `xcode` (os-level tools, not R) is (re)installed or updated. (Sorry, I know this isn't much.)

Comment: Hi @r2evans, thanks for the suggestion. I have XCode commandline tools installled and as far as I can tell it's the most recent version. I found some useful information in this [post](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/) as well, but didn't solve my problem. I might try just completely re-installing commandline tools.

Comment: OK, re-installing XCode commandline tools was not necessary in the end, one of the `rlang` developers [suggested an easier fix](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/972) by modifying the `.R/Makevars` file. Will add this as an answer.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.owsiak.org/r4-0-with-java-14-inside-macos-10-15-4/

Comment: @Oo.oO thanks for the suggestion. The fix I mentioned is very similar but adds the `CPPFLAGS` line to `~/.R/Makevars` instead of changing a file in the R framework. I'm not at all an expert so I don't know which option is best, but changing files installed by R itself does make me a bit uncomfortable...

Comment: @milanmlft Solution with `~/.R/Makevars` is way better. You don't have to touch system files. If it works for you, I'd have stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question on the `rlang` GitHub and one of the developers [suggested](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/972) the following fix:

1. Create `~/.R/Makevars` file (if not present already)
2. Add the following line to `~/.R/Makevars`:

```
CPPFLAGS += -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include
```

This seems to have solved the problem for me. **Note that this fix is for macOS 10.15 (Catalina) only**.

More useful information on the R toolchain for macOS can be found here: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/